# При нажатии на товар, открывается белая страница

Tags: reactjs, react-hook, react-router-dom, hosting

Не давно развернул react проект на хостинге. Но при нажатии на товар открывается новая страница и белый экран, кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой и как его решили ? Для открытия при нажатии на товар, я использую hook useParams

```
import { Routes, Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Register from "./pages/Register";
import Basket from "./pages/Basket";
import Product from "./pages/Product";
import ContactUs from "./pages/ContactUs";
import Payment from "./components/Payment";
import Favourites from "./pages/Favourites";
import AddressPayment from "./components/AddressPayment";
import Myorders from "./pages/Myorders";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter basename="/">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
        <Route path="/basket" element={<Basket />} />
        <Route path="/product/:id" element={<Product />} />
        <Route path="/contact" element={<ContactUs />} />
        <Route path="/payment" element={<Payment />} />
        <Route path="/myfavourites" element={<Favourites />} />
        <Route path="/myorders" element={<Myorders />} />
        <Route path="/basket/payment" element={<AddressPayment />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<Login />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

Здесь использовано hook и код для single page товара :

```
 import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
    import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
    import { getMyFavoriteList, getRetrieveProduct } from "../action/MainAction";
    
    import { addToCart } from "../redux/MainReducer";
    import ProductCartBox from "./ProductCartBox";
    
    import ColorsOfProduct from "./ColorsOfProduct";
    import SizesOfProduct from "./SizesOfProduct";
    import axios from "axios";
    import Swal from "sweetalert2";
    import AlotOfImgBox from "./AlotOfImgBox";
    import DOMPurify from "dompurify";
    
    import { AiFillHeart, AiOutlineHeart } from "react-icons/ai";
    import { MdKeyboardArrowLeft, MdKeyboardArrowRight } from "react-icons/md";
    
    const ProductCart = () => {
      const { id } = useParams();
    
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
      useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getRetrieveProduct(id));
        dispatch(getMyFavoriteList());
      }, [dispatch, id]);
    
      const dataPr = useSelector((state) => state.Data.getRetriveProductValue);
    
      const isDataLoaded = Object.keys(dataPr).length > 0;
    
      const getMyFavoriteListValue = useSelector(
        (state) => state.Data.getMyFavoriteListValue
      );
    
      const checkItem = getMyFavoriteListValue.find(
        (data) => data.product === dataPr.id
      );
    
      const colorValue = useSelector((state) => state.Data.colorValue);
      const sizeValue = useSelector((state) => state.Data.sizeValue);
      const loggedInUser = useSelector((state) => state.Data.loggedInUser);
    
      const addRemoveFavorite = async (id) => {
        console.log(id);
        if (Object.keys(loggedInUser).length === 0) {
          window.location.href = "/login";
        } else {
          if (!checkItem) {
            const data = {
              user: Number(localStorage.getItem("userID")),
              product: id
            };
            await axios({
              method: "POST",
              url: "https://pythonanywhere.com/api/tailor/favourite-create/",
              data
            })
              .then((resp) => {
                console.log(resp);
                if (resp.status === 201) {
                  dispatch(getMyFavoriteList());
    
                  Swal.fire({
                    position: "top-end",
                    icon: "success",
                    title: "Uğurla favorilərimə əlavə olundu",
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    timer: 800
                  });
                }
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
              });
          } else {
            await axios({
              method: "DELETE",
              url: `https://pythonanywhere.com/api/tailor/favourite-retrieve-update-delete/${checkItem.id}/`
            })
              .then((resp) => {
                console.log(resp);
                if (resp.status === 204) {
                  dispatch(getMyFavoriteList());
                }
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
              });
          }
        }
      };
    
      const [isSelectedImg, setIsSelectedImg] = useState("");
      useEffect(() => {
        setIsSelectedImg(isDataLoaded ? dataPr.image : "");
      }, [isDataLoaded, dataPr.image]);
    
      const clickImg = (imgUrl) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setIsSelectedImg(imgUrl);
        }, 300);
      };
    
      // slide of mini pictures
      let images = document.querySelector(".class_of_images");
    
      const prevBtn = () => {
        images.style.scrollBehavior = "smooth";
        images.scrollLeft -= 65; 
      }
    
      const nextBtn = () => {
        images.style.scrollBehavior = "smooth";
        images.scrollLeft += 65;
      }
    
    
      return (
        <div className="p_container">
          <div className="p_box">
    
            {isDataLoaded ? (
              <>
                <div className="images">
                  <div className="p_img">
                    <img src={isSelectedImg} alt="/" />
                  </div>
                  <div className="prod_img_container">
                    <MdKeyboardArrowLeft size={30} onClick={prevBtn} className="prod_img_btn"/>
                    <div className="class_of_images">
                      <div className="alotof_img_box" >
                        {isDataLoaded
                          ? dataPr.product_images.map((data, i) => {
                            return (
                              <AlotOfImgBox
                              key={i}
                              dataImgs={data}
                              onClick={() => clickImg(data.image)}
                              />
                              );
                            })
                            : ""}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <MdKeyboardArrowRight size={30} onClick={nextBtn} className="prod_img_btn"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="p_content">
                  <div className="product_title_category">
                    <h3>{dataPr.title}</h3>
                    {dataPr.categories && (
                      <i>
                        <span>{dataPr.categories[0].name}</span>
                      </i>
                    )}
                  </div>
    
                  <p className="p_price">
                    {dataPr.sale_price ? dataPr.sale_price : dataPr.price} AZN
                  </p>
    
                  <div
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                      __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(dataPr.characteristics)
                    }}
                  ></div>
                  <div>
                    <p className="color">Rəng:</p>
                    <ul className="p_color">
                      {dataPr.colors &&
                        dataPr.colors.map((data, i) => (
                          <ColorsOfProduct key={i} dataColor={data} />
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <p className="size">Ölçü:</p>
                    <ul className="p_size">
                      {dataPr.sizes &&
                        dataPr.sizes.map((data, i) => {
                          return <SizesOfProduct key={i} dataSizes={data} />;
                        })}
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div className="heart_add_to_basket">
                    <div className="basket">
                      <svg
                        width="12"
                        height="12"
                        viewBox="0 0 12 12"
                        fill="none"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      >
                        <path
                          d="M3 1L1.5 3V10C1.5 10.2652 1.60536 10.5196 1.79289 10.7071C1.98043 10.8946 2.23478 11 2.5 11H9.5C9.76522 11 10.0196 10.8946 10.2071 10.7071C10.3946 10.5196 10.5 10.2652 10.5 10V3L9 1H3Z"
                          stroke="white"
                          strokeLinecap="round"
                          strokeLinejoin="round"
                        />
                        <path
                          d="M1.5 3H10.5"
                          stroke="white"
                          strokeLinecap="round"
                          strokeLinejoin="round"
                        />
                        <path
                          d="M8 5C8 5.53043 7.78929 6.03914 7.41421 6.41421C7.03914 6.78929 6.53043 7 6 7C5.46957 7 4.96086 6.78929 4.58579 6.41421C4.21071 6.03914 4 5.53043 4 5"
                          stroke="white"
                          strokeLinecap="round"
                          strokeLinejoin="round"
                        />
                      </svg>
    
                      <button
                        className="add_to_card"
                        onClick={() => {
                          if (!sizeValue.size || !colorValue.color) {
                            Swal.fire({
                              position: "top-end",
                              icon: "error",
                              title: "Rəng və ölçü seçin",
                              showConfirmButton: false,
                              timer: 800
                            });
                          } else {
                            dispatch(addToCart(dataPr));
                          }
                        }}
                      >
                        Səbətə əlavə et
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div
                      className="heart"
                      onClick={() => addRemoveFavorite(dataPr.id)}
                    >
                      {checkItem ? <AiFillHeart /> : <AiOutlineHeart />}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </>
            ) : (
              <p>Yüklənir...</p>
            )}
          </div>
          <ProductCartBox />
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default ProductCart;
```

В консоли отображается только:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
7:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
```

Comment: Что есть "Товар", где указанный хук? Белый экран - а что в консоли при этом видно?

Comment: Подправил вопрос

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` - ошибка говорит, что обнаружен символ < , который не ожидался. Ищите, где эта ошибка вылезает. Тут либо синтаксическая ошибка, либо в передаваемых параметрах какие то спец символы

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что надо было прописать в package.json эту строку:

```
"homepage": "/",
```